# Comparing two hashmaps to equal keys and checking higher value

Tags: java, hashmap, comparison

I have two HashMaps

```
Map<String, String> mapA = new HashMap<>();
mapA.put("A", "1");
mapA.put("B", "3");
mapA.put("C", "1");
mapA.put("D", "5");

Map<String, String> mapB = new HashMap<>();
mapB.put("A", "2");
mapB.put("B", "2");
mapB.put("C", "4");
mapB.put("D", "2");
```

how to get the output below ?

```
Map<String, String> mapC = new HashMap<>();
mapC("A", "2");
mapC("B", "3");
mapC("C", "4");
mapC("D", "5");
```

Hashmap C with unique key and larger values.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question probably needs to be edited. You're still adding entries to `mapA` after creating `mapB`, and you're adding elements twice...

Comment: Note you should decide if the values should be numbers or strings as they don't compare the same way. 88 > 9 but "88" < "9"

Answer (score 4):

You may do it like so,

```
Map<String, Integer> keyToMaxValue = Stream.of(mapA, mapB)
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                e -> Integer.valueOf(e.getValue()), Integer::max));
```

And here's the output:

```
{A=2, B=3, C=4, D=5}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<objA, objB> mapA = new HashMap<objA, objB>();
mapA.put("A", "1");
mapA.put("B", "3");
mapA.put("C", "1");
mapA.put("D", "5");

Map<objA, objB> mapB = new HashMap<objA, objB>();
mapA.put("A", "2");
mapA.put("B", "2");
mapA.put("C", "1");
mapA.put("B", "1");
mapA.put("D", "2");
mapA.put("C", "4");



Map<objA, objB> mapC = HashMap<objA, objB>) mapA.clone();

 for(Map.Entry m:mapA.entrySet()){
            if(m.getValue()>mapB.get(m.getKey())){
                mapC.put(m.getKey(),m.getValue());
          }
            }
```

code piece for comparing and setting the new hash map

```
for(Map.Entry m:mapA.entrySet()){
        if(m.getValue()>mapB.get(m.getKey())){
            mapC.put(m.getKey(),m.getValue());
      }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Map<String, String> mapA = new HashMap<String, String>();
mapA.put("A", "1");
mapA.put("B", "3");
mapA.put("C", "1");
mapA.put("D", "5");

Map<String, String> mapB = new HashMap<String, String>();
mapB.put("A", "2");
mapB.put("B", "2");
mapB.put("C", "1");
mapB.put("B", "1");
mapB.put("D", "2");

Map<String, String> mapC = Stream.of(mapA, mapB)
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue(), (s1, s2) -> Integer.parseInt(s1) > Integer.parseInt(s2) ? s1 : s2));

System.out.println(mapC);
```